# Command + F1 did not shows the more... in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: software

When I view my `pom.xml` in IntelliJ IDEA, an error is shown:

> Dependency "org.springframework:spring-web:4.2.2.RELEASE" not found   more... (⌘F1)

However, when I use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, it doesn't show more information.

[image]

Comment: Did you try Fn/Cmd/F1 ?

Comment: I don't know the software, but it's always a good guess. It depends which way you have your F-keys set in prefs. Will put up an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which way the F-Keys respond is dependant on this pref

System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard > Use all F1, F2 etc. keys as standard function keys.

[image]

Unchecked, your F-Keys will change screen brightness, turn the volume up & down etc.
With it checked they become regular F-keys.

Holding  <kbd>Fn</kbd>  will temporarily flip this default for that one keypress.